# How does the % operator work in this solution to Project Euler #1

Tags: python

I started learning python not long ago and this was my original solution to Euler #1:

```
n = 0
for i in xrange(1000):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        n += i
print n
```

I found this online:

```
n = 0
for i in xrange(1000):
    if not i % 3 or not i % 5:
        n += i
print n
```

Both yield the correct answer (233168).

I don't really understand how the 'not x % y' part is evaluating as True/False when iterating over the range. Can someone clear this up?

Comment: If i is either divisible by  3 or 5 you just increment a count, what part do you not get?

Comment: I don't get what the 'not i % 3' and 'not i % 5' are doing in the second solution.

Comment: It means `if  i % 3 == 0` as 0 is a falsey value, it is just another way to write it

Comment: Zero is falsey: `bool(0)` evaluates to `false`. Also, I point at the very neglected step argument to `xrange`.

Comment: 0 is falsy and all other numbers are truthy. Since `6 % 3 == 0` it's falsy, while `7 % 3 == 1` and thus truthy.

Comment: Your original solution is better. Relying on integers (or arbitrary non-booleans) being "truthy" or "falsy" is just in bad programming taste, even when it saves a little typing - and in this case it doesn't.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen what do you mean?

Comment: `xrange(start, end, step)` :P so you don't have to generate all the numbers between 1 and 1000, just the ones you care about. My solution for this question was `sum(xrange(0,1000,3)) + sum(xrange(0,1000,5)) - sum(xrange(0,1000,15))`

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Clever

Answer (score 2):

The result of `x % y` would be True if it was not zero thus the following condition :

```
if not i % 3
```

is equal with `if i % 3 == 0`.

For better understanding see the following bool table :

```
 i % 3    | not i % 3      | i % 3 == 0

  True    |     False      |  True==0(false)-> False
  False   |     True       |  False==0(false)->True
```

Which shows that `(not i % 3) is equal with (i % 3 == 0)`.

**Note** that the True and False in table is just from `if` condition perspective not its result!

Comment: The `%` operator yields numbers (0, 1 and 2 in this case), not booleans.

Comment: @WolframH Im talking about `if` condition and python `if` condition assumes every number as True except 0 that is false!

Comment: @Kasra The table translates `i % 3 == 0` into `True==0` which I believe is confusing for people struggling with the meaning of `%`.

Comment: @WolframH You can just put a variable instead `i % 3 `. that's just for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is the modulo operator. In this example

`if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:`

It will be true if `i` is evenly divisible by 3 or 5.

The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [2].

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html